# יִבָּנֶה הַמִּקְדָּשׁ עִיר צִיּוֹן תְּמַלֵּא — why not תִּמָּלֵא?

Tags: hebrew, grammar-dikduk, shabbat-songs, beis-hamikdash, yerushalayim-jerusalem

The *Shabas* table song "*Tzur mishelo achalnu*" contains the following line:

> יִבָּנֶה הַמִּקְדָּשׁ עִיר צִיּוֹן תְּמַלֵּא
>
> *yibane hamikdash ir Tziyon t'male*
>
> the Temple should be built; you should fill the city of Zion

It seems so unpoetic to have the first half, "*yibane*", in *nif'al* [construction](http://he.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D7%91%D7%A0%D7%99%D7%99%D7%A0%D7%99%D7%9D_%D7%91%D7%A2%D7%91%D7%A8%D7%99%D7%AA) (and passive/intransitive), and the second, "*t'male*", in *piel* construction (and active/transitive). They could easily be balanced:

> יִבָּנֶה הַמִּקְדָּשׁ עִיר צִיּוֹן תִּמָּלֵא
>
> *yibane hamikdash ir Tziyon timale*
>
> the Temple should be built; the city of Zion should be filled

— with both in *nif'al* construction (and passive/intransitive). (We do find *timale* in that form in [*Shir Hashirim* 5:2](http://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%A9%D7%99%D7%A8_%D7%94%D7%A9%D7%99%D7%A8%D7%99%D7%9D_%D7%94_%D7%91).)

Why aren't they balanced?

Note that I wrote the above question based on the unpoeticness of the switch in construction. That is, I contend that *timale* is *better* (after *yibane*) and ask why it's not used. I suppose unpoeticness is [arguable](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D7%A2%D7%9C_%D7%98%D7%A2%D7%9D_%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%99%D7%97_%D7%90%D7%99%D7%9F_%D7%9C%D7%94%D7%AA%D7%95%D7%9B%D7%97). However, even if both forms (*timale* and *t'male*) are equally poetic, my question stands (albeit weaker): why switch constructions mid-sentence?

(Note that there is at least one prayer book in which *timale* is used, matching *yibane*: in "הסידור המדוייק איש מצליח (מהדורא רביעית) לפי מנהגי ונוסח הספרדים ועדות המזרח", according to a report I received via e-mail. But that's the only one I know of. I've checked a number of (mostly *Ashk'nazi*) prayer books and *Shabas*-song books, and all had *t'male*.)

Comment: I had always assumed most bentchers just didn't know dikduk...

Comment: In another forum, David Bannett noted: "Both Seligmann Baer and the Mateh Yehuda (peirush on zemirot by R' Yehuda Oppenheim in 'Shlosha S'farim Niftahim', zemirot with peirushim) refer one to Y'shayahu 33:5 where it says milei Tzion tz'daka (piel)." And I replied: "On the contrary, this is a reason not to use piel here, as it has bitransitive (has two objects) in Is.: 'fill X with Y'. Here, it's 'fill X' with the filling material implied, not stated. No?"

Comment: ...and Rabbi Seth Mandel noted (in part): [T]he verb m-l-’ becomes very complicated even in the T’NaKh.  See Ps. 72:19.  I would bet that the first reaction of most people, including the recondite denizens of Mesorah, would be to correct it to read “viymalle’ k’vodo et kol ha’aretz.”  Since HaZa’L established the nusach of t’filla based on myriad quotes from the T’NaKh, even hidden in places where most people don’t recognize them, it is conceivable that whoever composed the z’mira did the same. Give me rules that cover all cases of m-l-’ in the T’NaKh and then we can talk about z’mirot. [...]

Comment: [...] And even then personally I would spend my time doing other things (the Aramaic z’mirot in the Diwan, anyone?). Of course, I do not expect my comments to be part of the general thread.  I felt the need to say something because the discussion was so seriously high-minded.  One should treat grammar, unlike the Masorah of theT’NaKh, with a modicum of levity.

Comment: You mean when I say it correctly it's incorrect?

Comment: Ish Masliah is a great and very reliable Siddur. I would think to say that they have the correct Nusah.

Comment: If you want to check the accuracy and validity of Zemiroth in a Siddur, etc., the way to test it is by looking at the text they use for Yedid Nefesh.

Answer (score 2):

`t'male` mean : Hashem, you will fill the city of Zion, (with happy people, with buildings, with joy... and so on).

It can be written this way to mean that we should do ours and Hashem will complete our work.

Answer (score 2):

There are two equally valid ways of saying this verse, but they have completely different theological meanings.

The way you see it written means: The temple should be built, either by us, or by You, or by others, and You will then ensure that it is filled.

The way you want it to be written means: The temple should be built, either by us, or by You or by others, and we , or You, or others will fill it.

The first one, I believe becomes a request to fulfill the words of the prophets.
The second one, is a statement of hope that one day these things will happen.

Comment: I'm not seeing how the first is a request and the second merely a statement of hope. Can you explain, please, how the change in verb makes that difference?

Comment: Passive vs active. A passive thing is not a request, it's just a statement. The "You" in this context is obviously Hashem, and therefore a request. It's not a praise because the temple isn't standing.

Comment: Avi, even following the idea that only HaShem can fill the city, does that mean that for poetic purposes it would be wrong to ask that the city be filled? How is that theologically invalid?

Comment: @SethJ Where do you see me saying that one is theologically invalid? They just express different theological ideas.